# Is there a format specifier that works with Boolean values?

Tags: iphone, ios, string, format-specifiers

I want to do something like this:

```
NSLog(@"You got: %x", booleanValue);
```

where x is the specifier.  But I can't find one!  I want to avoid:

```
if (booleanValue) {
    NSLog(@"You got: YES");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"You got: NO");
}
```

Any ideas?  The docs didn't have a Boolean specifier.  `%@` didn't work either.

Comment: Whats funny is %x would work. (lower case hexadecimal specifier)

Comment: `%@` is the format specifier for an Objective-C object pointer. BOOL, Boolean, bool, etc. are not object types.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here are two things that work:

```
NSLog(@"You got: %@",booleanValue ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

or you can cast:

```
NSLog(@"You got: %d", (int)booleanValue);
```

Which will output 0 or 1

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the ? : switch!

Comment: You don't need the cast. `NSLog()` is variadic, `signed char` (which `BOOL` is) will be implicitly promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 9):

You can cast it to an int and use `%d`:

```
NSLog(@"You got: %d", (int)booleanValue);
```

Or use something like this:

```
NSLog(@"You got: %@", booleanValue ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: The cast is not necessary, see my comment on PengOne's answer.

Answer (score 5):

There's no format specifier that I know of. You can do this:

```
NSLog(@"You got: %@", (booleanValue ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

Alternately, you could write a little function or macro using the logic above that takes a BOOL and returns the appropriate string. You can then use that function in your log statements.

Answer (score 5):

For `os_log` use

```
os_log("results in true/false: %{bool}d", myBool)
os_log("results in YES/NO: %{BOOL}d", myBool)
```

If you are on the latest OS, you can also use string interpolation.
For more info look at [Format Custom Values in Message Strings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code#3666074)

As @MottiShneor pointed out, there is a more detailed list in the `os_log(3)` man pages:

```
Value type      Custom specifier         Example output
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOOL            %{BOOL}d                 YES
bool            %{bool}d                 true
darwin.errno    %{darwin.errno}d         [32: Broken pipe]
darwin.mode     %{darwin.mode}d          drwxr-xr-x
darwin.signal   %{darwin.signal}d        [sigsegv: Segmentation Fault]
time_t          %{time_t}d               2016-01-12 19:41:37
timeval         %{timeval}.*P            2016-01-12 19:41:37.774236
timespec        %{timespec}.*P           2016-01-12 19:41:37.2382382823
bitrate         %{bitrate}d              123 kbps
iec-bitrate     %{iec-bitrate}d          118 Kibps
uuid_t          %{uuid_t}.16P            10742E39-0657-41F8-AB99-878C5EC2DCAA
sockaddr        %{network:sockaddr}.*P   fe80::f:86ff:fee9:5c16
in_addr         %{network:in_addr}d      127.0.0.1
in6_addr        %{network:in6_addr}.16P  fe80::f:86ff:fee9:5c16
```

Comment: This is illuminating - and I've been searching for this very long - but WHERE have you found the documentation, the link only gives Swift alternatives, where is the list of possible value types in Objective-C ??? PLEASE help.

Comment: Here are the docs: they offer choosing between Swift and Obj-C but Apple (intentionally?) left nothing on the ObjC side --- it's all Swift. * https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/osloginterpolation?language=objc

Comment: You still need to tell me where you found the {bool} and {BOOL} specifiers, as they appear NOWHERE, and there are many others I don't know how to formalise.

Comment: last I found the documentation... it is only available in 'man os_log', and nowhere else.

Comment: Why it's not 'official docs' you ask? You know MacOS kernel to be named "XNU", right? which stands for "X is Not Unix".  MacOS has its conventions and sources of API information. Be they on the net, in Xcode, in the SDK headers, or otherwise. "man pages" are maintained to keep compatibility with BSD and POSIX lovers - they are by no means MacOS standard for anything. Of course it's nice to have info there too - but Apple is liable to provide that info in their "official" documentation too.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use the direct boolean formatting specifier %x

```
BOOL flag = YES;
NSLog(@"You got: %x", flag);
```

but at the very least, you can always rely on NSNumber objects, that 'remember' the 'type' of data they 'box' so this NSLog will also work fine:

```
NSLog(@"You got %@", flag? @YES : @NO);
```

Pay attention to the use of NSNumber literals - not strings.

Answer (score 1):

On `Swift`, use `String(describing: booleanValue)`

For example: `os_log("You got %@", log: .default, type: .debug, String(describing: booleanValue))`

Comment: This will print: `You got true` or `You got false` in the console.

os_log is unified logging method, you can read about it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging

Comment: you can use both `%s` and `%@` on some cases, but `%@` is better

Comment: %s is for primitive c-strings, and %@ is for Objective-C objects, and will in turn call the [x description] method on the object, to provide its string interpretation. it's not "better" but suitable for other things. However, you need neither of these with primitive boolean values, as os_log has its specific descriptor for booleans: os_log("You got %{bool}d", booleanValue)

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Here is the code:

```
NSLog(@"%hhd",BOOLvariable);
```

Prints 1 for Yes and 0 for No. Worked for me.

Comment: Throws a warning as of iOS10 (possibly sooner) `%i`, however, no longer throws a warning even without explicit (int) casting.