# Why does neither C nor Objective-C have a format specifier for Boolean values?

Tags: objective-c, c, format-specifiers

The app I'm working on has a credit response object with a Boolean "approved" field.  I'm trying to log out this value in Objective C, but since there is no format specifier for Booleans, I have to resort to the following:

```
NSLog("%s", [response approved] ? @"TRUE" : @"FALSE");
```

While it's not possible, I would prefer to do something like the following:

```
NSLog("%b", [response approved]);
```

...where "%b" is the format specifier for a boolean value.

After doing some research, it seems the unanimous [consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752082/is-there-a-format-specifier-that-works-with-boolean-values) is that neither C nor Objective-C has the equivalent of a "%b" specifier, and most devs end up rolling their own (something like option #1 above).

Obviously Dennis Ritchie & Co. knew what they were doing when they wrote C, and I doubt this missing format specifier was an accident.  I'm curious to know the rationale behind this decision, so I can explain it to my team (who are also curious).

**EDIT:**
Some answers below have suggested it might be a localization issue, i.e. "TRUE" and "FALSE" are too English-specific.  But wouldn't this be a dilemma that all languages face? i.e. not just C and Objective-C? Java and Ruby, among others, are able to implement "True" and "False" boolean values. Not sure why the authors of these langs didn't similarly punt on this choice.

In addition, if localization were the problem, I would expect it to affect other facets of the language as well. Take protected keywords, for instance. C uses English keywords like "include", "define", "return", "void", etc., and these keywords are arguably more difficult for non-English speakers to parse than keywords like "true" or "false".

Comment: Your first code snippet uses `%s` with Objective-C string literals (`@""`). Either use `%@` or use C string literals. Also, you could wrap the selection of a string for a boolean in an inline function: `static inline NSString* bool_name(BOOL val) { return val ? @"TRUE" : @"FALSE"; }` and then `NSLog(@"%@", bool_name([response approved]));`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pure C (back to the K&R variety) doesn't actually have a boolean *type*, which is the fundamental reason why native `printf` and cousins don't have a native boolean format specifier. Expressions can evaluate to zero or nonzero integral values, which is what is interpreted in `if` statements as false or true, respectively in C. (Understanding this is the key to understand the semantics of the delightful `!!` "bang bang operator" syntax.)

([C99 did add a `_Bool` type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdbool.h), though unless you're using purest C you're unlikely to need it; derived languages and common platforms already have common boolean types or typedefs.)

The `BOOL` type is an ObjC construct, and `-[NSString stringWithFormat:]` (and `NSLog`) simply doesn't have an additional format specifier that does anything special with it. It certainly could (in addition to `%@`), and choose some reasonable string to drop in there; I don't know whether such a thing was ever considered, but it strikes me anyway as different in kind from all other format specifiers. How would you know to appropriately localize or capitalize the string representations of "yes" or "no" (or "true" or "false"?) etc? No other format specifier results in the library making decisions like that; all others are precisely numeric or insert the string result of another method call. It seems onerous, but making you choose what text you actually want in there is probably the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

What should the formatter display? 0 & 1? TRUE & FALSE? YES & NO? -1 and 1? What about other languages?

There's no good consistently right answer so they punted it to the app developer, for whom it'll be a clearer (and still simple) choice.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a dilemma that all languages face?  i.e. not just C and Objective-C?  Java and Ruby, among others, are able to implement "True" and "False" boolean values.  Not sure why the authors of these langs didn't similarly punt on this choice.

In addition, if localization were the problem, I would expect it to affect other facets of the language as well.  Take protected keywords, for instance.  C uses English keywords like "include", "define", "return", "void", etc., and these keywords are arguably more difficult for non-English speakers to parse than keywords like "true" or "false".

Comment: @toomanyrichies Reasonable question re: Java and Ruby. Re: locales, I'd suggest there's a distinction between actual language keywords ("void", "return") that exist and have meaning only in source, versus strings that the library would utilize at runtime, which a user might end up seeing.

Answer (score 0):

In C early days, there was no numeric `printf()` specifier for `char`, `short` either as there was little need for it.  Now there is `"%hhd"` and `"%hd"`.  Any type narrower than `int/unsigned` was promoted.

Today, in C, `_Bool` type maybe printed with `"%d"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  _Bool some_bool = 2;
  printf("%d\n", some_bool); // prints 1 (or 0 when false)
  return 0;
}
```

The missing link in C is its lack of a format specifier to *scan* into a `_Bool`.  This leads to various solutions like the following which are not satisfactory with input like "T" or "false".

```
  _Bool some_bool;
  int temp;
  scanf("%d", &temp);
  some_bool = temp;
```